# Re-raising exceptions in Python 2.x with added context information

Tags: python, exception, python-2.x

### C# background

I come from a C# context where you can catch an exception and throw a new one including the original one as an inner exception. This way you can have something like this:

```cs
void LoadPlugin(string configFile)
{
    try
    {
        OpenAndReadConfig(configFile);
        DoMoreStuff();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new PluginException("Could not load plugin", ex);
    }
}

void OpenAndReadConfig(string configFile)
{
    try
    {
        OpenFile(configFile); // file does not exist
        DoStuff();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ConfigurationException("Error reading configuration", ex);
    }
}
```

So if some code calls `LoadPlugin(@"non\existing\file.xml")` you would have the following exception chain, with each exception retaining its own stack trace:

- PluginException: Could not load plugin

  - ConfigurationException: Error reading configuration

    - FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\non\existing\file.xml'

### Python question

Now I'm working in some library code on Python 2.6 and I would like to achieve something similar. After looking through several SO questions and blogs/forums I came up with a solution that seems good enough for me, but since my experience with Python is limited I don't know if there are some caveats that I'm missing. My idea is to do something like this:

```py
def open_and_read_config(config_file):
    try:
        open_file(config_file) # file does not exist
        do_stuff()
    except Exception, ex:
        ex.args = ('Error reading configuration',) + ex.args
        raise

def load_plugin(config_file):
    try:
        open_and_read_config(config_file)
        do_more_stuff()
    except Exception, ex:
        ex.args = ('Could not load plugin',) + ex.args
        raise
```

This way I would preserve the original exception's message and traceback, while being able to add context information. One drawback I can see is that this only allows me to add context information on the form of a message string, but not a new exception type (e.g. `ConfigurationError` or `PluginError`). Also, the traceback will be preserved only for the original (innermost) exception.

So, is there anything else I'm missing? Any reason why you would recommend against using this approach?

Comment: This is a non-issue. You can create your own exception subclass that has the same behaviour of C# exception. I believe in python3 this kind of things has become easier to do.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you have only one traceback - for the last created exception. If you want to split tracebacks, you should obtain current traceback in `except` clause and `raise` new exception with appropriate type with this traceback and nested exception, i.e.:

```
import traceback
class TracebackableException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, traceback, inner=None):
        self.message = message
        self.traceback = traceback
        self.inner = inner

class ConfigurationException(TracebackableException): pass
class PluginException(TracebackableException): pass
```

...

```
def open_and_read_config(config_file):
    try:
        open_file(config_file) # file does not exist
        do_stuff()
    except IOError, ex:
        raise ConfigurationException("Cannot load config", traceback.format_exc(), ex)

def load_plugin(config_file):
    try:
        open_and_read_config(config_file)
        do_more_stuff()
    except Exception, ex:
        raise PluginException("Cannot load plugin", traceback.format_exc(), ex)
```